# Are available urllib2 module with HTTPCookieProcessor function for Python 2.2?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, pys60

I'm using Python S60 (PyS60) with Python 2.2 engine.
i already have urllib2 module but HTTPCookieProcessor doesn't exist

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> dir(urllib2)
['AbstractBasicAuthHandler', 'AbstractDigestAuthHandler', 'AbstractHTTPHandler', 'BaseHandler', 'CacheFTPHandler', 'CustomProxy', 'CustomProxyHandler', 'FTPHandler', 'FileHandler', 'GopherError', 'GopherHandler', 'HTTPBasicAuthHandler', 'HTTPDefaultErrorHandler', 'HTTPDigestAuthHandler', 'HTTPError', 'HTTPHandler', 'HTTPPasswordMgr', 'HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm', 'HTTPRedirectHandler', 'HTTPSHandler', 'OpenerDirector', 'OpenerFactory', 'ProxyBasicAuthHandler', 'ProxyDigestAuthHandler', 'ProxyHandler', 'Request', 'StringIO', 'URLError', 'UnknownHandler', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__path__', '__version__', '_opener', 'addinfourl', 'base64', 'build_opener', 'dis', 'encode_digest', 'ftplib', 'ftpwrapper', 'getproxies', 'gopherlib', 'httplib', 'inspect', 'install_opener', 'localhost', 'md5', 'mimetools', 'mimetypes', 'noheaders', 'os', 'parse_http_list', 'parse_keqv_list', 'posixpath', 're', 'rfc822', 'sha', 'socket', 'splitattr', 'splitgophertype', 'splithost', 'splitport', 'splitquery', 'splittype', 'stat', 'sys', 'time', 'token', 'tokenize', 'types', 'unquote', 'unwrap', 'url2pathname', 'urlopen', 'urlparse']
```

Answer (score 1):

[urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#httpcookieprocessor-objects) was added in Python 2.4, so it’s not available in your version of Python. I’d advise you to upgrade to a newer version of Python 2, as Python 2.2 is already nine years old.

I just looked up the PyS60 thing and it seems that there is no newer version (although I’m not sure on that, their version numbering scheme is a bit weird), so you might not be able to upgrade that. What you could try is to backport the `HTTPCookieProcessor` type from Python 2.4+. But that might not work if other internals changed that are necessary for that.

Looking at [its source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ceec209b26d4/Lib/urllib2.py#l1033) (in Python 2.4, to not introduce too many changes from later versions), it does seem very simple, so it might work out well. At least it’s worth a try.